# how to make draggable elements of an html variable produced by an javascript array

Tags: javascript

A javascript array (jArray) has 5 elements.
I pass them into the HTML array (hArray).
Now, I want to drag elements out of hArray (let's say number 10) into the hFrame.
This last one is not working.

That is the problem is how we make draggable elements of an html variable 
produced by an javascript array. The examples I have found regard a fixed number of elements, predefined in html. Here is about a sequence of words, of uknown length, produced by javascript.

Thank you all of you in advance.

```
<!-- THIS IS THE FRAME TO SEND THE DRAGGABLE ELEMENTS -->
<div id="hFrame";
style="text-align: left;
border:1px solid white;
width: 350px;
height: 200px;
padding: 10px";
ondrop= "drop(event)";
ondragover= "allowDrop(event)"></div>

<!-- THIS IS THE HTML VARIABLE hArray -->
<div id="hArray"></div>

<!-- THESE ARE THE FUNCTIONS FOR DRAGGING -->
<script>
    function drag(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }

    function allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }
</script>


<!--  THIS IS THE SCRIPT FOR PRODUCING THE jArray WHICH PASSES ITS ELEMENTS TO hArray -->
<script>
    class Array {
        constructor(){
            this.length=0; 
            this.data={}; 
        }
        push(element){ 
            this.data[this.length]=element; 
            this.length++; 
            return this.length
        } 
        getElementAtIndex(index){ 
            return this.data[index]; 
        }
    }

//pushing element  
    const jArray= new Array();
    jArray.push(12); 
    jArray.push(13);
    jArray.push(14); 
    jArray.push(10); 
    jArray.push(989);

    for (var y=0; y< jArray.length; y++) {
        document.getElementById("hArray").innerHTML += jArray.getElementAtIndex(y) + " ";
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Prevent usage of reserved keywords or interfaces to create new classes. You'll overwrite the already existing `Array` global object.

Comment: I do not use reserved keywords. I use hArray and jArray which are not reserved. But any other name, instead of these, produces the same. The class Array is from another example used widely, and it does not cause problem too. Thank you anyway for your comment. I shall take care for that in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a few things:

1. Set ondragstart event for draggable item
2. Set attribute `draggable` as true
3. Define attribute `id` for draggable item

So, you loop should be like this:

```
for (var y=0; y< jArray.length; y++) {
    document.getElementById("hArray").innerHTML += '<span draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id=' + y + '>' + jArray.getElementAtIndex(y) + "</span> " ;
}
```

See my full example in sandbox:
https://jsfiddle.net/denisstukalov/73zntmvd/29/#&togetherjs=tVJr9JjkUn

Comment: It works !!! Thank you very much !!! It was a very clever solution.